# Trouble opening repository with NodeGit

Tags: node.js, git, libgit2, nodegit

I'm trying to use [nodegit](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nodegit) to open up a git repository with the following code:

```
var git = require('nodegit');

git.Repo(repoPath, function(error, repository) {
  if (error) throw error;
}
```

This gives me the following error, no matter what I assign the `repoPath` variable:

```
git.Repo(repoPath, function(error, repository) {
    ^
Error: git_repository is required.
```

I have tried path to local folder, I have tried path to local folder, including the `.git` folder, I have tried a remote repo using url. No nothing.

Can anyone help out?

I'm using
 node v0.10.24
 nodegit v0.1.4.
 git  1.9.0.msysgit.0
 win 8.1 pro 64bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `open` method to open the repository.

```
git = require('nodegit')
git.Repo.open('some-path', function(err, repo) {
  console.log(repo.path())
}
```

Using a remote path won't work as git works locally. If you'd like to clone, there's a `clone` method available which will also call a function once the clone has been performed, like

```
git = require('nodegit')
git.Repo.clone('git://some-host/path', 'local-path', null, function(err, repo) {
  console.log(repo.path())
}
```

Comment: Great! I have copy-pasted the example from the website (http://www.nodegit.org/). Looks like the example in the readme is a little different. I'll try follow that instead. Thanks.